# aws_imagebuilder_component issue with template_file

Tags: bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to deploy a bash script using aws_imagebuilder_component resource;  I am using a template_file to populate an array inside my script.  I am trying to figure out the correct way to render the template inside the imagebuilder_component resource.

I am pretty sure that the formatting of my script is the main issue :(

This is the error that I keep getting, seems like an issue with the way I am formatting the script inside the yml, can you please assist? I have not worked with image builder previously or with yamlencode.

Error: error creating Image Builder Component: InvalidParameterValueException: The value supplied for parameter 'data' is not valid. Failed to parse document. Error: line 1: cannot unmarshal string `phases:...` into Document.

```
# Image builder component
resource "aws_imagebuilder_component" "devmaps" {
  name     = "devmaps"
  platform = "Linux"
  data = yamlencode(data.template_file.init.rendered)
  version  = "1.0.0"
}

# template_file
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/myscript.yml")}"
  vars = {
    devnames= join(" ", local.devnames)
  }
}



# myscript.yml
schemaVersion: 1.0
phases:
  - name: build
    steps:
      - name: pre-requirements
        action: ExecuteBash
        inputs:
          commands: |
            #!/bin/bash    
            for i in `seq 0 6`; do
                nvdev="/dev/nvm${i}n1"
                if [ -e  $nvdev ]; then
                    mapdev="${devnames[i]}"
                    if [[ -z "$mapdev" ]]; then
                        mapdev="${devnames[i]}"
                    fi
                    else
                        ln -s $nvdev $mapdev
                        echo "symlink created: ${nvdev} to ${mapdev}"
                    fi
                fi
            done
```

@Marko

```
# tfvars
vols = {
  data01 = {
    devname = "/dev/xvde"
    size        = "200"
  }
  data01 = {
    devname = "/dev/xvdf"
    size        = "300"
  }
}
```

Variables.tf: populating this list "devnames" from the map object "vols", shown above

```
locals {
  devnames = ([ for key, value in var.vols: value.devname ])
}
```

main: template_file is using the list "devnames" to assign its values to devnames variable; devnames variables is used inside myscript.yml

```
devnames = join(" ", local.devnames)
```

At this point, everything is working w/o issues

But when this is executed, it fails and complains about the formatting of the template that was rendered using myscript.yml.
I am doing something wrong here that I cannot figure it out

```
## Image builder component
resource "aws_imagebuilder_component" "devmaps" {
  name     = "devmaps"
  platform = "Linux"
  data = yamlencode(data.template_file.init.rendered)
  version  = "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using `templatefile`: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile. If you don't use `yamlencode` do you get an expected result?

Comment: @MarkoE - same error without yamlencode                                                                           │ Error: error creating Image Builder Component: InvalidParameterValueException: The value supplied for parameter 'data' is not valid. Parsing step 'pre-requisite' in phase 'build' failed. Error: line 1: cannot unmarshal string `#!/bin/...` into []string.

Comment: Using tempfile introduced a new error that Iv fixed in template_file `data = templatefile("${path.module}/myscript.yml", join(" ", local.devnames))`                                Error >>>> `local.devnames is tuple with 4 elements`

Comment: You have to define the variable name from the file and assign it a value, i.e.: `devnames = join(" ", local.devnames)`.

Comment: Already defined, it worked with template_file                                                                           `locals {
  devnames = ([ for key, value in var.vols: value.devname ])
}
`

Comment: The issue that I am having trouble with is the formatting of `myscript.yml`
I am not really sure how to make it work for image_builder resource

Comment: I meant when calling `templatefile`. The syntax is `templatefile(file, vars)`. So it would have to be `templatefile("${path.module}/myscript.yml", { devnames = join(" ", local.devnames)})`.

Comment: This syntax is invalid, you do not need the extra { before join
`data = templatefile("${path.module}/myscript.yml", { join(" ", local.devnames)})`

Comment: Ok, and if that is the case, which variable will pick up the value of the `join` and how?

Comment: Not sure, sorry I am not really an expert; I did try it and it failed tho. When I use join with template_file, it works w/o issues.

Comment: Well, that's the reason I was trying to explain how to use templatefile, but if everything works then I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: No I was only referencing "join", it works with template_file and does not work or me with templatefile.

The issue that I am having is with `yamlencode` that I have no clue how to fix

Comment: Can you post the values of variable `vols` and `devname`? I cannot reproduce the issue without those.

Comment: thanks @MarkoE for looking into this; I have edited my post above to respond to your question.

Comment: @MarkoE - you are right, templatefile() is the way to go. 

This worked for me
  `myvar = templatefile("${path.module}/myscript.yml", {
    devnames = local.devnames
    })`

Comment: Yup, that is what I was aiming for a couple of days ago. :D